# mutiplying in Matrix class with 2D vectors

Tags: c++

I am declaring a 2 dimensional vector and I want to overload multiplication operator for it in a Matrix class, but I do not know how to fill the elements with set function correctly

```
class Matrix{

    public:
        Matrix();
        Matrix(int,int);
        Matrix(vector<vector<double>>identity);
        void set(int , int , int);
        int get(int , int);
        Matrix operator+(const Matrix &);
        Matrix operator*(const Matrix &);
        Matrix operator-(const Matrix &);
        Matrix operator=(const Matrix &);
       ~Matrix();
    private:
        int row,column;
        std::vector<vector<double>>mat;
};
void Matrix::set(int r,int c ,int e){
   mat[r][c]=e;
}
//overloading * operator
Matrix Matrix::operator*(const Matrix &b)
{
   int result=0;
   for(int i=0 ; i< this->mat.size() ; i++){
       for(int j=0 ; j< this->mat[i].size ; j++){
           for(int k=0 ; k< b.mat[i].size() ; k++){
             result[k]+=(this->mat[i][j]*b.mat[j][k]);
             result.set(i,j,result[k]);
           }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: what is the problem? Do you get compiler errors? Does it crash? Wrong results?

Comment: Well, for one, if `void set(int , int , int);` is declared within the class, and `void set(int r,int c ,int e){ mat[r][c]=e; }` is outside the class, clearly something is missing: *the class name*. That implementation should be `void Matrix::set(...`. Regardless, your multiplication implementation looks broken. You need to review your algorithm.

Comment: also `result[k]` looks fishy, your `Matrix` has no `operator[]` declared.

Comment: you need to include the error message in the question and you should ask a specific question. You dont need our help to compile it and see what the errors are ;)

Comment: I do not know how to write the algorithm of multiplying operator with using this set function above

Comment: would you please help to write the algorithm?? :(

Comment: Oh I see what you're trying to achieve! Your question needs some further clarification btw. So, why do you need the `set()`? It's useless in the `operator * ()` function since `std::vector` provides you with a `[]` operator to access the correct element.

Comment: I need it because it is a task and I suppose to use set function

Comment: your usage of `set` inside `operator*` seems to be fine, though I cannot say the same for everything else in `operator*` ... why cant you tell us what particular error you are trying to fix? Asking for the complete correct code is not a question but a request for code, which I'd consider as offtopic

Comment: the error is no match for operator  [ ]

Comment: because you call `result[k]` but your matrix has no `operator[]`. Thats completely unrelated to the `set` method. Please do include the error message in the question!

Comment: @JeJo quite, but not exactly, the method should still return a new `Matrix`

Comment: @JeJo nope it is `operator*=` that should return `*this`. `operator*` is supposed to return a new object

Comment: I do not know how to use set to fill the elements

Comment: could anybody help with this???

Comment: I would like to help you, but the code you provided is incomplete (some methods are declared but not defined) and there are a couple of other errors not related to the question (plus you still refuse to include the error message in the question, but lets leave that aside). This is as far as I got before giving up https://wandbox.org/permlink/uffAuIIEgWyfeU7z

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for cannot be done using the `operator * ()`. The reason is because the member function `set()` will mutate the class, i.e. change the values in the elements of the member array of the object. The `operator * ()` returns a copy of a `Matrix` object. It does not modify the existing object.

The `set()` can be utilized using the `operator *= ()` which is meant to modify the current object.

Here is an example of how it can be used. **Note** that the example below is written very quickly. It is just to illustrate the different operator overloading cases.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

template<typename T>
using Array2D = std::vector<std::vector<T> >;

struct Matrix
{
    Array2D<double> m;

    Matrix(std::size_t rows_, std::size_t columns_)
    {
        m.resize(rows_);
        for (auto &&r : m)
        {
            r.resize(columns_);
            std::fill(r.begin(), r.end(),0.0);
        }
    }

    Matrix(Array2D<double> &&m_) : m(std::move(m_))
    {;}

    Matrix(const Matrix &mat_) : m(mat_.m)
    {;}

    void print()
    {
        for (const auto &r : m)
        {
            for (const auto &c : r)
                std::cout<< c <<" ";
            std::cout<<std::endl;
        }
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }

    void set(std::size_t row_, std::size_t column_, double value_)
    {
        m[row_][column_] += value_;
    }

    Matrix operator * (const Matrix &mat_)
    {
        auto rows = m.size();
        auto cols = m[0].size();
        auto cols2 = mat_.m[0].size();

        Matrix tmp(rows,cols2);
        for(std::size_t r=0; r<rows; ++r)
        {
            for(std::size_t c=0; c<cols2; ++c)
            {
                for(std::size_t k=0; k<cols; ++k)
                {
                    tmp.m[r][c] += this->m[r][k] * mat_.m[k][c];
                }
            }
        }
        return tmp;
    }

    Matrix& operator *= (const Matrix &mat_)
    {
        auto rows = m.size();
        auto cols = m[0].size();
        auto cols2 = mat_.m[0].size();

        Matrix tmp(*this);
        for(std::size_t r=0; r<rows; ++r)
        {
            for(std::size_t c=0; c<cols2; ++c)
            {
                this->m[r][c] = 0.0;
                for(std::size_t k=0; k<cols; ++k)
                {
                    set(r,c, tmp.m[r][k] * mat_.m[k][c]);
                }
            }
        }
        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Matrix m1 = {{
                    {1,2,0},
                    {0,1,0},
                    {1,2,1}
                }};

    Matrix m2 = {{
                    {0,1,2},
                    {1,2,0},
                    {2,0,0}
                }};

    Matrix m3 = m1*m2;
    m3.print();

    m3 *= m1;
    m3.print();
}
```

The result is:

```
2 5 2 
1 2 0 
4 5 2 

4 13 2 
1 4 0 
6 17 2
```

Online code example: https://rextester.com/ZGRI81514

Comment: cheers, i'll remove the noise

Comment: @user463035818: Thanks for your comments.